# ElasticSearch bool should_not filter

Tags: elasticsearch, boolean, range

I'm a newbie in elasticsearch, so my question is:

There are 3 sections in bool filter:

```
must
    All of these clauses must match. The equivalent of AND. 
must_not
    All of these clauses must not match. The equivalent of NOT. 
should
    At least one of these clauses must match. The equivalent of OR.
```

How do I perform a "should_not" query?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: please explain your definition of 'should_not'

Answer (score 26):

In order to get something like "should_not" please try the following query:

```
GET /bank/account/_search
{
   "size": 2000,
   "query": {
      "bool": {
          "must": {
             "match_all": {}
          }, 
         "should": {
            "bool": {
               "must_not": {
                  "match": {
                     "city": "XYZ"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

In this case the clause "must" is required to retrieve the all results (the result with the city "XYZ" too) but with decreased score for this specific one.

Comment: How would you go about this with nested queries?

Answer (score 9):

That depends on how exactly you are wishing a "should_not" to function.

Since `should` is roughly equivalent to a boolean OR (i.e. return documents where A or B or C is true), then one way to think of "should_not" would be roughly equivalent to **NOT (A OR B OR C)**. In boolean logic, this is the same as NOT A AND NOT B AND NOT C. In this case, "should_not" behavior would be accomplished by simply adding all your clauses to the `must_not` section of the bool filter.

Comment: This implies that accomplishing should_not requires you to always wrap the clause inside another bool query. That works but is annoying from an API perspective. You simply want the negation of a clause but you are using a Bool query to accomplish it. This is feels odd when you have only one clause. For example, you want to return documents where (A ∨ B ∨ (¬C)).    NOT query was deprecated in elasticsearch and replaced with calls in Bool query like must_not, but they never added a should_not.

Answer (score 2):

This query similar to sql 
***where categoryId=  "category123"  AND (localeId != "de_DE" OR productId != "productMediatest-productid01")***

```
{
  "query": {
   "bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "term": {
        "categoryId": "category123"
      }
    },
    {
      "bool": {
        "should": [
          {
            "bool": {
              "must_not": {
                "term": {
                  "localeId": "de_DE"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "bool": {
              "must_not": {
                "term": {
                  "productId": "productMediatest-productid01"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a not filter and then a should filter for should_not operation.

```
  "filter": {
       "not": {
          "filter": {
              "bool": {
                  "should": [
                     {}
                  ]
              }
          }
       }
   }
```

Comment: I'm using elastic search 2.1, and i think the NOT Query  is deprecated in 2.1, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-not-query.html