# Elasticsearch query null check for two fields with OR condition

Tags: elasticsearch, jboss, java-7, elasticsearch-dsl

I want to alter the data in elastic search with a java 7 application running on jboss server. In elastic search index there are two fields called city_id and country_id. With new implementation I need to search for **city_name** is null or **country_name** null records and update them with relevant city_name and country_name.

```
POST index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": "2023-02-27 06:40:00"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
         {
          "exists": {
            "field": "city_name"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "country_name"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 3,
  "sort": [{
            "timestamp": {
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm using this search query. But with this its search for **city_name and country_name both null** records. I want to get **OR** (city_name OR country_name null) condition for this.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since should is roughly equivalent to a boolean OR, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35061299/elasticsearch-bool-should-not-filter), you could try using a nested `should` -> `bool` -> `must_not` clause. Example:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                    "bool": {
                        "must_not": {
                            "exists": {
                                "field": "city_name"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must_not": {
                            "exists": {
                                "field": "country_name"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```